# How to create temp table in a dynamic database connection in SSIS 2014

Tags: ssis

I am using dynamic database connection in a for loop which executes for 13 databases.Each time I have to create a temp table to retrieve data from a different connection to this connection and use it for rest of the loop.I am using an OlEDB database connection having Server and Initial catalogue variable dyanamically changed for 13 connection. Now  I have made RetainSameConnection=true for the database connection because of the temp table creation.But because of this same data is getting loaded 13 times as the connection is not getting closed after opening for the first time. I want to know if there is any way I can make the connection open only during the for loop and change the connection in the next loop run. Thanks in advance,Pallabi

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a Temp table?

Comment: I need to do a join with different tables of two servers which does not have any linked server in between..I wanted to execute it with SQL query itself as its much faster than merge join transformation

Comment: Why not use a real table if it's a large table, or an object variable if it's a small table?